# Kibana scripted field which loops through an array

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, metricbeat

I am trying to use the metricbeat http module to monitor F5 pools.

I make a request to the f5 api and bring back json, which is saved to kibana. But the json contains an array of pool members and I want to count the number which are up.

The advice seems to be that this can be done with a scripted field. However, I can't get the script to retrieve the array. eg

```
doc['http.f5pools.items.monitor'].value.length()
```

returns in the preview results with the same 'Additional Field' added for comparison:

```
[
 {
  "_id": "rT7wdGsBXQSGm_pQoH6Y",
  "http": {
   "f5pools": {
    "items": [
     {
      "monitor": "default"
     },
     {
      "monitor": "default"
     }
    ]
   }
  },
  "pool.MemberCount": [
   7
  ]
 },
```

If I try

```
doc['http.f5pools.items']
```

Or similar I just get an error:

```
"reason": "No field found for [http.f5pools.items] in mapping with types []"
```

Googling suggests that the doc construct does not contain arrays?

1. Is it possible to make a scripted field which can access the set of values? ie is my code or the way I'm indexing the data wrong.
2. If not is there an alternative approach within metricbeats? I don't want to have to make a whole new api to do the calculation and add a separate field

-- update.

Weirdly it seems that the number values in the array do return the expected results. ie.

```
doc['http.f5pools.items.ratio']
```

returns

```
 {
  "_id": "BT6WdWsBXQSGm_pQBbCa",
  "pool.MemberCount": [
   1,
   1
  ]
 },
```

-- update 2

Ok, so if the strings in the field have different values then you get all the values. if they are the same you just get one. wtf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, solved it.

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/problem-looping-through-array-in-each-doc-with-painless/90648

So as I discovered arrays are prefiltered to only return distinct values (except in the case of ints apparently?)

The solution is to use `params._source` instead of `doc[]`

Comment: if anyone can explain why I will accept your answer

Answer (score 2):

I'm adding another answer instead of deleting my previous one which is not the actual question but still may be helpful for someone else in future.

I found a hint in the [same documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/modules-scripting-fields.html#modules-scripting-doc-vals):

> Doc values are a columnar field value store

Upon googling this further I found this [Doc Value Intro](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/docvalues-intro.html) which says that the doc values are essentially "uninverted index" useful for operations like sorting; my hypotheses is while sorting you essentially dont want same values repeated and hence the data structure they use removes those duplicates. That still did not answer as to why it works different for string than number. Numbers are preserved but strings are filters into unique.

> This “uninverted” structure is often called a “column-store” in other
>   systems. Essentially, it stores all the values for a single field
>   together in a single column of data, which makes it very efficient for
>   operations like sorting.
>
> In Elasticsearch, this column-store is known as doc values, and is
>   enabled by default. Doc values are created at index-time: when a field
>   is indexed, Elasticsearch adds the tokens to the inverted index for
>   search. But it also extracts the terms and adds them to the columnar
>   doc values.

Some more [deep-dive into doc values revealed it a compression technique](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/_deep_dive_on_doc_values.html#_column_store_compression) which actually de-deuplicates the values for efficient and memory-friendly operations.

Here's a NOTE given on the link above which answers the question:

> You may be thinking "Well that’s great for numbers, but what about
>   strings?" Strings are encoded similarly, with the help of an ordinal
>   table. The **strings are de-duplicated** and sorted into a table, assigned
>   an ID, and then those ID’s are used as numeric doc values. Which means
>   strings enjoy many of the same compression benefits that numerics do.
>
> The ordinal table itself has some compression tricks, such as using
>   fixed, variable or prefix-encoded strings.

Also, if you dont want this behavior then you can [disable doc-values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/_deep_dive_on_doc_values.html#_disabling_doc_values)

Comment: I think you found it. there seem to be a few unintuitive things about kibana/elastic

Comment: Yeah, this is more on the data structure part which was not easy to understand. But definitely good to know. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 1):

[The answer for why `doc` doesnt work](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-fields.html#modules-scripting-doc-vals)

*Quoting below:*

> Doc values are a columnar field value store, enabled by default on all
>   fields except for analyzed text fields.
>
> **Doc-values can only return "simple" field values like numbers, dates,
>   geo- points, terms, etc, or arrays of these values if the field is
>   multi-valued. It cannot return JSON objects**

Also, important to add a *null check* as mentioned below:

> **Missing fields**
>
> The doc['field'] will throw an error if field is
>   missing from the mappings. In painless, a check can first be done with
>   doc.containsKey('field')* to guard accessing the doc map.
>   Unfortunately, there is no way to check for the existence of the field
>   in mappings in an expression script.

[Also, here is why `_source` works](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-fields.html#modules-scripting-stored)

*Quoting below:*

> The document _source, which is really just a special stored field, can
>   be accessed using the _source.field_name syntax. The _source is loaded
>   as a map-of-maps, so properties within object fields can be accessed
>   as, for example, _source.name.first.

.

Responding to your comment with an example:

The kyeword here is: ***It cannot return JSON objects***. The field doc['http.f5pools.items'] is a *JSON object*

Try running below and see the mapping it creates:

```
PUT t5/doc/2
{
   "items": [
     {
      "monitor": "default"
     },
     {
      "monitor": "default"
     }
    ]
}


GET t5/_mapping

{
  "t5" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "doc" : {
        "properties" : {
          "items" : {
            "properties" : {
              "monitor" : {  <-- monitor is a property of items property(Object)
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it will depending on the values and mapping. Whether its analyzed or not. The answer is all in the documentation.

Comment: can you point me to the bit in the documentation that says arrays are prefiltered to unique values when the value is a string?

Comment: It doesnt say those exact words but it says **It cannot return JSON objects**. The field `doc['http.f5pools.items']` is a JSON object.

Comment: @Ewan Also added an example. Hopefully that adds some clarity

Comment: I think you are missing the point. I understand it cant return the object. But it can return the fields of the object as arrays. except, when the field type is a string its returns only the _distinct_ values rather than all the values

Comment: the question is _why_ does it return only distinct values? is it by design or a bug?

Comment: You're right. I was assuming the question was _why params._source works instead of doc[]_.

Comment: @Ewan That is an interesting behavior. I didnt know the answer, but i think i found it and i'm glad to learn something new today :) +1 for that